# What does わけ do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> そんなスゴイ御方は、ヒューマンのお店でアルバイトをしてしまっている**わけ**だけど。勿論、お金を稼いで明日を生き抜くためだ。

What meaning does わけ give to that sentence? Is it indicating a reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read [this question?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2250/9749)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, わけ doesn't mean reason. It emphasizes that something is a natural result and can be omitted. 
Ex:

- 彼があまりにできるからヘッドハンターの目に留まったというわけだ。(He came to the headhunter's attention because he was so competent.)
  Here, 〜ヘッドハンターの目に留まった。 is also fine.
- No wonder he didn't get my e-mail. I didn't send it! (彼がメールを受け取らなかったわけだ。私が送らなかったんだから！)
- This building is really solid. No wonder it survived the earthquake. (本当に頑丈な作りの建物ですね。あの地震にも耐えて残ったわけだ)
- そういうわけだ。(That's the story. / That's what this is all about.)

Comment: If it "emphasizes that something is a natural result", then how could it be omitted, since omitting it would remove that emphasis and thereby change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Yes. I should explain a little bit more. Even if it is omitted, we can still make  natural sentences (without meaning of emphasis). Ex. 彼はあまりにできるからヘッドハンターの目に留まった。／彼はメールを受け取らなかった／あの地震にも耐えて残った／そういうことだ／