# 嘘なわけ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> それは嘘なわけだが、

I don't understand. Does it say "it's a lie" or "it may be a lie"? I think I've read from a previous thread that な here is the equivalent of だ, but I'm stuck at わけ.

Comment: This may not be helpful in this case but the question on わけだ is one of the best ones on this site in my opinion. [How to end a sentence in わけ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/how-to-end-a-sentence-in-%e3%82%8f%e3%81%91)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My dictionary says this type of わけ is used to confirm a (known) fact before diving into a main discussion. Context is missing, but I feel the speaker is trying to imply it's an *obvious* lie. So the nuance is something like "*Of course* it's a lie, but ..." or "*As you know*, it's a lie, but ..." Naturally, it may sound scornful if said referring to someone else's statement.

> - [知っての通り](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%9F%A5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8A)、我々の会社は赤字を出している訳ですけれども、…
> - ハハハ、まあ今言ったことは冗談な訳ですが、今から言うことは大事です。…
> - さて、今日は私の誕生日な訳だけど、プレゼントはどこ？ まさか忘れたの？

な is an attributive form of copula だ. It typically appears before explanatory-の, もの, ので or のに. But in casual speech it's sometimes used before こと, わけ, 理由, 場合, etc.

> - 彼はもう大学生**な**のだ。
> - 彼はもう大学生**な**のに、マナーを知らない。
> - 彼が大学生**な**[ものか](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=monoka)！
> - 彼が大学生**な**ことを知らなかった。 (大学生であること is better in formal settings)
> - 彼が大学生**な**訳がない。 (大学生である訳/大学生の訳 is better in formal settings)
> - 大学生**な**人 (nonstandard and highly informal, but occasionally heard instead of 大学生の人/大学生である人)

Answer (score 3):

My dictionary says that this わけだ is the soft way of saying of だ that means "conclusion".

It means ""it's a lie". It  is the equivalent of それは嘘だが, but the author would think it is a bit strong.

Comment: Could you explain (easily) why it is 嘘なわけ rather than 嘘というわけ or 嘘のわけ? The dictionaries I've looked through say that 嘘 is not a 形容動詞. If this requires a longer explanation or you'd rather someone else answer, I have no problem posting this as a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: Naruto"s answer would help you.

Comment: In addition, な is used in this usage like 彼女は大学生なわけよ. But when わけ is used  as the meaning of "reason", の can be used like 彼女が大学生のわけ, though な is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means "It's a lie."

> I think I've read from a previous thread that な here is the equivalent of だ,

This isn't quite correct. You cannot substitute な for だ to end a sentence or following a -na adjective or noun preceding the と particle. In this case, わけ requires that its qualifying clause have an adjectivized suffix if it doesn't end in a verb (i.e. you need one if it ends in any kind of adjective or noun), so nouns end up following the pattern of -na adjectives and have a な suffix added.

So 嘘なわけ is the same in terms of grammar as saying 面白いわけ or 綺麗なわけ.