# N + NO/NA/DA + わけ and generic rule?

Tags: grammar

I found in dictionary わけ is a Noun, However, I see in the book that Noun will go with な when using with わけ, as N な + わけがない/わけはない.

Besides わけ, is there any Japanese word that has that exception?

Why has it become like that?
And there is any general rule for us to remember?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If N is a pure noun such as 学生 or 食べ物, N**の**わけがない is the norm in formal settings. N**な**わけがない is usually acceptable, but tends to sound colloquial. な is sometimes used also before 理由, こと, 場合, etc. If N is a na-adjective (aka descriptive noun) such as 簡単, simply な should be used. Nだわけがない is always ungrammatical.

See also: [嘘なわけ in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58009/5010)