# What does わけ mean in this sentence

Tags: meaning

The sentence is as follows:

これが兄様がすべてを託した**わけ**なのですか？

From the structure of the sentence this わけ doesn't appear to be a sentence ending particle, and I'm struggling to interpret it. I find that dictionaries unfortunately do not actually explain this word in a way that is meaningful for those who don't already understand how it is used.

To provide some context, the person currently speaking is watching the person that their 兄様 entrusted something to before their death, where they were also present at this time. The current time of the statement is as they are watching the person commit, for lack of a better word, war atrocities in order to do what they were asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to end a sentence in わけ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/how-to-end-a-sentence-in-%e3%82%8f%e3%81%91)

Comment: @Mindful, No, that's 「[full sentence]+わけだ。」. The sentence in question here is  「これが[relative clause]わけだ。」, right? 「これが兄様がすべてを託した」 is not a full sentence, you see?

Comment: @Chocolate sure, I recognize the difference, this is just a fairly thorough treatment of わけ and the original question seems to be about usages of わけ in general (of course the example sentence is a question). The usage here looked a little bit like #1, although looking closer they may not really be sufficiently similar except in the sense that わけ has to do with a result of some kind. Perhaps I should've just left it here as something related in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

わけ, 訳 is defined as

> conclusion from reasoning, judgement or calculation based on something read or heard; reason; cause; meaning; circumstances; situation

When わけ comes at the end of a sentence you can think of it as translating to "so that means...(the previous words in the sentence), etc". In this case, "So this is why 兄様 left everything to you?". The speaker is making a conclusion based on something read or heard.

It has, what I call, continuous form as というわけで、そういうわけで、i.e. "for that/this reason... blah blah". You'll hear this a lot in Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

"the case":

____わけなのですか = is it the case that ___?